# Get marionette child view by attribute

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a compositeView and corresponding collection.

I have an attribute value by witch I want to get childView of this compositeView.

How to do this?

I have no idea so far ...

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

compView.children.findByModel(collection.get({id: elId}))